# What's the difference between Wanam Xposed and Wanam Kit?

Tags: root-access, xposed-framework

Is there a difference between Wanam Kit and Wanam Xposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanam Kit is for AOSP roms, Wanam Xposed is for Touchwiz according to this video from XDA developers (official youtube channel)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U273PvWKrVs

Answer (score 0):

**There is no difference**

Xposed modules are applications by themselves. Xposed Installer (the one that you use to manage the modules) offers a simple way to browse these .apk files that you can install afterwards. So, since at the end the app is installed, it doesn't matter whether you install it from the Play Store or the Xposed Installer.

Comment: I know how modules work, but there is a module called Wanam kit and one call Wanam Xposed

Comment: But thanks for the information anyway.